# Apps or metadata that mentions the name of any other mobile platform will be rejected

Tags: ios, objective-c, itunes-store

I am working on a app to provide online  service for mobile repair. For which I have shown all the mobile company and their names in the apps pages.

Thats why Apple rejected the app due to the copyright issue.

Can someone help me in this respect for which I thank you in advance.

Comment: Well...just a suggest...you can use parse, give Apple different data, then when ur app got accepted, u can just change the data in parse, then ur app work as u want, but still, that workaround can get ur app banned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is removed the company mobile names from the image file name and the mobile images.